# How to display a list based on date in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to build a real simple event listing app that list a bunch of event based on Dates. I'm fairly new and was wondering how would I display a list or table based on dates? This is what I have now.

```
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Link</th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= event.title %></td>
    <td><%= event.description %></td>
    <td><%= event.link %></td>
    <td><%= event.date %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I would like it display in a date format. For example all events under the date of February/21 will appear under that specific heading.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<% @events.group_by(&:date).each do |date, events| %>
  <tr><td colspan="7"><h1><%= date %></h1></td></tr>
  <% events.each do |event| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= event.title %></td>
    <td><%= event.description %></td>
    <td><%= event.link %></td>
    <td><%= event.date %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help! I wanted more of a way to display all dates under one heading. For example, say i have a h1 for February 20th and a h1 for February 21st. I want all the events under the 20th to display under the heading for Feb. 20th and 21st events for the 21st.

Comment: One more question! Right now it's grouping the most future date. Is it possible to make it sort by the most recent upcoming date?